# How do I tell UserManager.FindByNameAsync to include a relation?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

I am using ASP.NET Identity 2.2.0 with ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 and Entity Framework 6.1.2.

I added a new property and its corresponding table to my database using ASP.NET Identity with Code First like so:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
  [ForeignKey("UserTypeId")]
  public UserType Type { get; set;}
  public int UserTypeId { get; set;} 
}

public class UserType
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set;}

  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, from some action, when I call:

```
var user = UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
```

It does get the user with the correct `UserTypeId` because that is a primitive, but it does not get the `UserType` property of the `ApplicationUser` class.

If I were not using this abstraction, I would either call `LoadProperty<T>` or the `Include` method in Entity Framework to include the navigational property or relation named `Type` (of type `UserType`) on the `ApplicationUser` class.

How do I do that with ASP.NET Identity's `UserManager`? I suspect the only way would be to override this method in my custom `UserManager` derived class and do it myself?

Comment: Have you tried making the `Type` property of your `ApplicationUser` class `virtual`?

Comment: Thank you. That did it. Many thanks. If you post that as an answer, please? :-)

Comment: So it wasn't able to proxy it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Entity Framework lazy loading, you need to ensure that your navigation properties are marked as `virtual`.

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    [ForeignKey("UserTypeId")]
    public virtual UserType Type { get; set;}
    public int UserTypeId { get; set;} 
}
```

Alternatively if you are unable/don't want to use lazy loading, then you can still use your context as you would any other entity:

```
var user = context.Users.Include(u => u.Type).Single(u => u.UserName == userName);
```

Comment: this does not apply anymore to Entity Framework Core. Lazy loading is disabled no matter if you use `virtual`.
https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html#lazy-loading

Comment: @iberodev Well this question isn't tagged with EF Core so that's not an issue. In fact EF Core doesn't even support lazy loading yet, though it is on the roadmap, expect it to work in the next major release.

Comment: Perhaps overriding the user store users to include custom child entities will work, cases like one to many without navigationId column on the users table